# How to transfer backups from old external HDD to new external HDD?

Tags: finder, hard-drive, backup, time-machine, ssd

1.Finder doesn’t work.
It shows wrong size,my backup is 27GB,but when I’m trying to copy,it magically become 200GB.When I’m trying to copy this 200Gb file,I get infinity copying because the size of file keeps growing like 198/200> 199/200 > 200/200 > 201/201 > 202/202 etc…

2.Carbon Copy doesn’t work.
I got this error 3
“ Time Machine backup volumes use Apple-proprietary filesystem devices, and Apple does not support the use of third-party utilities to copy Time Machine backups. Use Finder to copy this proprietary data store to another disk.”

3.SuperDuper! Says : “Failed to copy files from HDD to USB”

I don’t know what to do.

PS
**It is not similar to another post because I described what I tried and what didn’t work.
Those methods were suggested by users in another question and these methods didn’t work,so don’t delete it please.**

Comment: @anonymous SuperDuper doesn’t work,check number 3

Comment: Oh! Sorry, i didnt read the post thoroughly. Maybe you can try dd? Its the unix utility to copy a disk using the terminal. Keep in mind, it will keep the partition the same size, so if the usb is smaller, you will need to make the hdd’s tm partition smaller. If you need more help with dd, i can help. This guide should help you: https://linuxconfig.org/how-dd-command-works-in-linux-with-examples

Comment: You might also be able to get away with cp (terminal command for copy). In terminal, enter sudo cp -rw /Volumes/oldTM/* /Volumes/newTM/